# how to get text from textbox with dynDateTime

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010

I still didn't get why i can't get text from textbox.

I need dynDateTime to get date to textbox, but after i choose the date and the date appear in text box, i can't get the text from the text box.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").dynDateTime({
                showsTime: false,
                ifFormat: "%Y/%m/%d",
                daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m,  %Y",
                align: "BR",
                electric: false,
                singleClick: false,
                displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
                button: ".next()"
            });
        });
    </script>
```

```html
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ReadOnly = "true" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox><img src="../../images/calendar_icon.png" />
```

what did i miss?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

apparently, the problem is just ReadOnly = "true".

delete them and i can get the text from textbox.

silly me..

thanks for read though..

:D